# Give values to each form in a formset in Django

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, formset

I am trying to create a formset which each contain an input field. This will have some dynamic number of elements, and once the form is submitted the inputted text will be assigned as "tags" to an associated object. This may sound kind of confusing so lets look at the form class I am trying to make:

```
class TagsForm(forms.Form):

    tags = forms.CharField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        applicantId = kwargs.pop('applicantId')

    def saveTags(self):
        applicant = Applicants.objects.get(id=applicantId)
        Tag.update(applicant,tags)
```

As you can see I would like to pass the form an applicant's id, then upon recieving the post request update the tag for that applicant object by calling each forms saveTags. Here is the code from my view where I am handling this:

```
    ...
    applicantQuery = allApplicantsQuery.filter(**kwargs)
    TagsFormSet = formset_factory(TagsForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tags_formset = TagsFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='tags')
        if tags_formset.is_valid()
            for tagForm in tags_formset:
                tagForm.saveTags()
    else:
        tags_formset = TagsFormSet(prefix='tags')
    ...
```

The problem is I don't know how to create the initial set of forms with id's from the applicantQuery queryset. Ideally i can just loop through the queryset and send the applicant.id to each form, but I'm not sure how to do this. I also feel I should mention the formset should have exactly the same number of forms as applicants in applicantsQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom formset.

```
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet

class TagFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        applicants = kwargs.pop('applicants')
        super(TagFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #after call to super, self.forms is populated with the forms

        #associating first form with first applicant, second form with second applicant and so on
        for index, form in enumerate(self.forms):
            form.applicant = applicants[index]
```

Now you don't need to override `__init__` of TagsForm.

Now each of your form is associated with an applicant. So, you can remove the first line of your `saveTags()`. So saveTags() become:

```
def saveTags(self):
    #applicant was set on each form in the init of formset
    Tag.update(self.applicant, tags)
```

Your view code:

```
applicantQuery = allApplicantsQuery.filter(**kwargs)

#notice we will use our custom formset now
#also you need to provide `extra` keyword argument so that formset will contain as many forms as the number of applicants
TagsFormSet = formset_factory(TagsForm, formset=TagFormSet, extra=applicantQuery.count())

if request.method == 'POST':
    tags_formset = TagsFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='tags', applicants=applicantQuery)
    if tags_formset.is_valid()
        for tagForm in tags_formset:
            tagForm.saveTags()
else:
    tags_formset = TagsFormSet(prefix='tags', applicants=applicantQuery)
```